# jqGrid wrong data format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

Im trying to put some data into jqGrid and force it to be displayed in a treeview.
My problem is, the 6th item (cid=6) is not showing in the grid. The 4th item looks like it has some subitems, but expanding this branch shows nothing. The 6th item is nowhere to find in the tree (I suppose, I've defined it as subitem of cid4).

[image]

Here is a working example of this code http://jsfiddle.net/498jhxcg/
(my production code uses POST/AJAX/JSON, the example is changed to localdata. Grid is displayed  in the same wrong way in both cases.)

Is the data in wrong format, or the jqgrid is wrong defined? (btw. changing parent_id to parentid did not helped.)

```
var myjsondata = '{"rows":[ 
{"cid":"1","name":"cat1","lvl":"0","parent_id":"null","isleaf":true,"expanded":false,"loaded":true},
{"cid":"2","name":"cat2","lvl":"0","parent_id":"null","isleaf":false,"expanded":false,"loaded":true},
{"cid":"3","name":"cat3","lvl":"1","parent_id":"2","isleaf":true,"expanded":false,"loaded":true},
{"cid":"7","name":"cat7","lvl":"1","parent_id":"2","isleaf":true,"expanded":false,"loaded":true},
{"cid":"4","name":"cat4","lvl":"0","parent_id":"null","isleaf":false,"expanded":false,"loaded":true},
{"cid":"6","name":"cat6","lvl":"1","parent_id":"4","isleaf":true,"expanded":false,"loaded":true},
{"cid":"5","name":"cat5","lvl":"0","parent_id":"null","isleaf":true,"expanded":false,"loaded":true}
],"records":7,"total":1}';

$('#jgtable').jqGrid({
ExpandColumn:'id',
datastr: myjsondata,
datatype: 'jsonstring',    
colNames: [
    'Id',
    'Name',
    'Parent id',
    'isLeaf?',
],
colModel: [
    { index: 'cid', name: 'cid', width:"75px"},
    { index: 'name', name: 'name', width:"75px"},
    { index: 'parent_id', name: 'parent_id',width:"75px"},
    { index: 'isleaf', name: 'isleaf', width:"75px"},
],
pager: '#pager',
rowNum: 10,
rowList:[2, 10, 25, 50, ],
height: 'auto',
minHeight: '250px',
recordpos: 'right',
viewrecords: true,
gridview: false,
treeGrid: true,
treeGridModel : 'adjacency',
treedatatype: "local",             
treeReader : {
    level_field: "lvl",
    parent_id_field: "parent_id", 
    leaf_field: "isleaf",
    expanded_field: "expanded",
    loaded_field: "loaded",
    index_field: "cid",
},
jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: false,             
},
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you should add `key: true` property to the definition of `cid` column. You can use alternatively (or to do both things) the option `jsonReader: { id: "cid" }`. In the case the value of `cid` property of input data will be interpreted as the id of the item and the value from `parent_id` will be correct.

see http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/498jhxcg/19/